# Publish messages that could not be de-serialized to DLT topic

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I do not understand how messages that could not be de-serialized can be written to a DLT topic with spring kafka.

I configured the consumer according to the [spring kafka docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.2.3.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#dead-letters) and this works well for exceptions that occur after de-serialization of the message.

But when the message is not de-serializable a `org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException`is thrown while polling for messages.

Subsequently, `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler.handle(Exception thrownException, List<ConsumerRecord<?, ?>> records, ...)` is called with this exception but with an empty list of records and is therefore unable to write something to DLT topic.

How can I write those messages to DLT topic also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the exception is thrown by the Kafka client itself so Spring doesn't get to see the actual record that failed.

That's why we added the `ErrorHandlingDeserializer2` which can be used to wrap the actual deserializer; the failure is passed to the listener container and re-thrown as a `DeserializationException`.

See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.4.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#error-handling-deserializer).

> When a deserializer fails to deserialize a message, Spring has no way to handle the problem, because it occurs before the poll() returns. To solve this problem, version 2.2 introduced the ErrorHandlingDeserializer2. This deserializer delegates to a real deserializer (key or value). If the delegate fails to deserialize the record content, the ErrorHandlingDeserializer2 returns a null value and a DeserializationException in a header that contains the cause and the raw bytes. When you use a record-level MessageListener, if the ConsumerRecord contains a DeserializationException header for either the key or value, the container’s ErrorHandler is called with the failed ConsumerRecord. The record is not passed to the listener.

The `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer` has logic to detect the exception and publish the failed record.